# How can I highlight a row in a gtk.Table?

Tags: python, colors, gtk, pygtk

I want to highlight specific rows in a `gtk.Table`. I also want a mouseover to highlight it w/ a different color (like on a link in a web browser). I thought of just packing each cell with an eventBox and changing the `STATE_NORMAL` and `STATE_PRELIGHT` bg colors, which does work, but mousing over the eventbox doesn't work. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
    def attach(w,c1,c2,r1,r2):
        eb = gtk.EventBox()
        a = gtk.Alignment(xalign=0.0,yalign=0.5)
        a.add(w)
        eb.add(a)
        eb.set_style(self.rowStyle)
        def ene(eb,ev):
            eb.set_state(gtk.STATE_PRELIGHT)
        def lne(eb,ev):
            eb.set_state(gtk.STATE_NORMAL)
        eb.connect('enter-notify-event', ene)
        eb.connect('leave-notify-event', lne)

        self.table.attach(eb, c1, c2, r1, r2,
                          xoptions=gtk.EXPAND|gtk.FILL,
                          yoptions=gtk.SHRINK)
```

It only highlights each cell at a time, so I'll have to change the notify events to light up everything.

EDIT: `self.rowStyle` is set as follows:

```
tmpeb = gtk.EventBox()
st = tmpeb.get_style().copy()
st.bg[gtk.STATE_PRELIGHT] = gtk.gdk.Color(65535,65535,0)
self.rowStyle = st
```

I create an `EventBox` just to get its style.

Comment: `help(gtk.EventBox.set_style)` gives me only `set_style(...)`, and it is not clear what `self.rowStyle` is in your case. I'm trying to achieve something similar (highlight every second row), and I guess this is nearly the answer for my question, I would appreciate it if you would elaborate this answer a bit more.

Comment: @swege: updated, does that help? would appreciate an upvote if so =)